# finding windows xp activation key on existing installation

Tags: windows-xp, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to retrieve license information](https://superuser.com/questions/43196/best-way-to-retrieve-license-information)

The kid's computer is infested with viruses, and I want to wipe it clean and reinstall XP.
I can't find the XP CD and box with the key sticker anymore. I have an installation CD from MSDN but for correctness reasons would like to use the original personal license.
Is there a way to find out the activation key for the currently installed instance?

Control Panels -> System shows registered to, with a registration number, but it doesn't look like an installation key (i.e. it's only digits, not alphanumeric)

Comment: More here: http://superuser.com/questions/43196/best-way-to-retrieve-license-information

Comment: And here http://superuser.com/questions/32367/recovering-a-windows-xp-license-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the (open source!) [Magical Jelly Bean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/).

Answer (score 1):

[**Jelly Bean**](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) is probably the most popular. Here's some alternatives though:

[**WinKeyFinder**](http://www.winkeyfinder.com/remository/winkeyfinder/win-keyfinder-1.73-rc2.php):

[image]

[**Keyfinder Thing**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/gr/keyfinderthing.htm):

[image]

[**LicenseCrawler**](http://www.klinzmann.name/licensecrawler.htm):

[image]